# Unable to create either a new project or user

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have deployed an Ubuntu Openstack Setup with Autopilot. Following the [official instructions](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot)

Everything seems to be working fine, I can launch an instance and create new networks, but for some reason I cannot create a new project, or new users. My Ubuntu OpenStack environment consists of 8 machines. Does anyone know if the [unlicensed version](https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/plans-and-pricing) is restricted in any way? On the website it doesn't seems that way

---

**Official Statement**

*OpenStack Autopilot*

*The quickest and easiest way to install and manage Ubuntu OpenStack is to use Canonical's OpenStack Autopilot. Autopilot users also get full access to Landscape systems management free of charge for up to 10 machines.*

Answer (score 1):

There are no such restrictions, it appears you are encountering a configuration bug.

Comment: Any idea where in the configuration I could fix this bug? Like altering config files? Tnx!